# does VS 2008 supports template?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates

when run this  tinny code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>
using namespace std;


template <class T>

int main(){

return 0;
}
```

it writes suddenly errors

```
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Documents and Settings\STUDENT\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\heap_tree\Debug\heap_tree.exe    heap_tree
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   MSVCRTD.lib heap_tree
```

does VS 2008 supports templates?

Comment: yes it does: this is proved by the fact that you get the link error :]

Comment: then what is wrong  with my code?

Comment: afaik the C++ standard says that main should be declared as either `int main()` or `int main( int argc, char **argv )` or equivalent. You have no such declaration (because you put template) hence the linker complains your program does not have a main function.

Comment: but i have int main(),i am confused,can you show me simple example?

Comment: you don't have `int main()`. You have `template< class T > int main()`, that is not the same. I suggest you read up about templates in order to understand why it is not the same, as I cannot explain that with a simple example.